# How to show many same data in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a case about query in mysql.First i have a column called "cola" from table "abc" then i want to select or show it.This is what i do

i assume that i have just only one data "a"

```
select cola from abc
```

it will show table like this :

```
   ------
   |cola|
     a
```

My question is what if i want to select the table and it shows many rows but same value like this

```
   ------
   |cola|
     a
     a
     a
```

it shows 3

what i know is just use limit

```
select cola from abc limit 3
```

but doesnt work

thanks

Comment: attempt please.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use union:

```
select cola from abc
union all
select cola from abc
union all
select cola from abc
```

Comment: union removes duplicates - I think you meant to use `UNION ALL`.